# How do I get the question someone says in a string option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have the following code. The result I would want from it is a response from the bot that says:
"[DISCORD-USER] Asked [question which is inputted as a string option]."

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, Embed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('8ball')
        .setDescription('Answers any question, given that it has a yes or no asnwer')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('question')
                .setDescription('Write the yes or no question you want the answer to.')
                .setRequired(true)),
                
    async execute(interaction) {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor ('2f3136')
        .setAuthor({ name: (`${interaction.user.tag} Asks ${interaction.reply(question)}`)})
    
        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    },
};
```

Obviously, `${interaction.reply(question)}` does not work. Could someone please tell me what I need to write there which would do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

To get the user input for the command option set by `.addStringOption(option => option.setName('question'))`, you can use `interaction.options.getString('question')`.

You can check out [the documentation on `CommandInteractionOptionResolver`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver) where you'll find all the methods you may need:

```js
// .addStringOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('string').setDescription('Enter a string'),
// )
const string = interaction.options.getString('string');

// .addIntegerOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('integer').setDescription('Enter an integer'),
// )
const integer = interaction.options.getInteger('integer');

// .addNumberOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('number').setDescription('Enter a number'),
// )
const number = interaction.options.getNumber('number');

// .addBooleanOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('boolean').setDescription('Select a boolean'),
// )
const boolean = interaction.options.getBoolean('boolean');

// .addUserOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('target').setDescription('Select a user'),
// )
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
const member = interaction.options.getMember('target');

// .addChannelOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('channel').setDescription('Select a channel'),
// )
const channel = interaction.options.getChannel('channel');

// .addRoleOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('role').setDescription('Select a role'),
// )
const role = interaction.options.getRole('role');

// .addAttachmentOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('attachment').setDescription('Attach something'),
// );
const attachment = interaction.options.getAttachment('attachment');

// .addMentionableOption((option) =>
//   option.setName('mentionable').setDescription('Mention something'),
// )
const mentionable = interaction.options.getMentionable('mentionable');
```